# Show custom grid and chooser inside product edit UI form

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, ui-form

I want to show a grid inside product edit UI form under a fieldset Related Blog Post. This section would allow choosing a list of related blog posts for a product. I am using a custom module for blog page.

Just need some guidance on loading data custom collection inside product edit UI form with mass blog selector(similar to how we select related/upsell products).

Below is a reference image

[image]

Has anyone done anything similar?